# Condition implying the product of two ideals is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, and let $I,J$ be nonzero ideals. I want to understand why there is an $R$-ideal $H$, relatively prime to $J$, such that $HI$ is principal (this is a line in a proof of Mollin's Algebraic Number Theory).

If $I$ is principal, then the result is clear since we can take $H=R$. Otherwise, I'm having trouble understanding why this is true. I also am just having trouble thinking of an example of taking the product of a non-principal ideal with another ideal and getting something pricipal. How should the proof proceed?

Answer (score 1):

In Dedekind domains ideals are inversible so that $a\in I \implies (a)=IH$.

Assume $H$ is never coprime with $J=\prod_j P_j^{e_j}$ this implies $I = \bigcup_j I P_j$ 
so that $(a)=HI = \bigcup_j  (a)P_j$ and $R =  \bigcup_j P_j$ which is a contradiction because $1$ is in no prime ideal.